# Sending HTML email in PHP

Tags: php, html, html-email

I am working on an HTML page where i need to send confirmation by HTML email using PHP.
I don't have much experience in PHP as i occasionally work on PHP.

I am able to send the HTML email using PHP and it comes up nice except the IMAGE part.

I have checked about 30 example and implement different ways of but non works.

When i check the source code of email it shows image part as

```
<img src="http://www.xyz.com/images/emailheader.jpg\&quot;"> 
<img src="http://www.xyz.com/images/emailheader.jpg\&quot;;" alt="mage&quot;">
```

**Code for HTML**

```
$subject = 'Confirmation';
$message = '<table ><tr><td><img src=\"http://www.xyz.com/images/emailheader.jpg\" /></td></tr><tr><td >'. "\r\n";
$message .= '<img src=\"http://www.xyz.com/images/emailheader.jpg\"; alt="Image" />';
$message .= 'Title <br/><br/>'. "\r\n";
$message .= 'Dear '. $_SESSION['FN'] . ' '.$_SESSION['LN'].'<br/><br/>'. "\r\n";
$message .= ' <br/><br/>'. "\r\n";
$message .= 'Name: '. $_SESSION['FN'] . ' '.$_SESSION['LN'].'<br/>'. "\r\n";
$message .= 'Email: '. $_SESSION['Email'].'<br/>'. "\r\n";


$message .= '<br/><br/>.'. "\r\n";

$message .= '<br/><br/>Best Regards,'. "\r\n";

$message .= '</td></tr></table>';

//Headers
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: booking@xyz.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: abc@xyz.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

ini_set ( "SMTP", "smtp.abc.com" );
```

I would appreciate if some can correct my code or at-least tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: It should be against my atheist principles to help you out, but nevertheless - don't compose HTML yourself. No, really don't `:)`. Use something like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) instead.

Comment: why are you using semicolon at the and of .jpg. please look my answer.

Comment: @Turgut Dursun : It was show in few example online so i did it the same way & i was wondering why it was not works. Thanks it is working now .

Comment: @StudentDubai - as it stands, this email won't contain a text-part message, which is easily dealt with if you use a library. Sending email has all sort of weird idiosyncrasies, which library authors have already tackled for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

problem is in this line:

```
'<img src=\"http://www.alfarooqcentre.com/images/emailheader.jpg\"; alt="Image" />';
```

remove "\" and ";"

or check this tutorial, there is what you want.

http://phpform.net/html_mail.php