# PHP text/html multipart email appears as raw text in hotmail

Tags: php, email, multipart

I am testing an auto reply multipart email using PHP. The problem is when I receive the email in my hotmil, the whole content (including html and the random hashes) appears as raw text. Here is my code:

```
$cname = "test";
$to = "me@myemail.com";
$autoReplyTo = "me@myemail.com";
$autoReplySubject = "Enquiry";

$mime_boundary = md5(date('U'));

$autoReplyheaders = "From: XXXXX <" . $to . ">" . "\r\n" .
                    "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" .
                    "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=$mime_boundary" .
                    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit". "\r\n";


$plain_text = "Dear " . $cname . ".\r\n";
$plain_text = "Thank you for contacting us.\r\n";
$plain_text .= "We are currently processing your query and will contact you shortly. We appreciate the time and interest you have shown in our company.\r\n";
$plain_text .= "Sales Team\r\n";
$plain_text .= "Note: This is an auto-generated email, please do not reply.\r\n";


$html_text = '<html><head><title>AUTO REPLY</title></head><body>';
$html_text .= '<p><img src="http://www.xxxxxx.xx/images/logo.png" /></p>';
$html_text .= '<p>Dear '.$cname.',<br />
    Thank you for contacting us.<br />
    We are currently processing your query and will contact you shortly.<br />
    We appreciate the time and interest you have shown in our company.</p>';

$html_text .= '<p><b>Sales Team</b></p>';
$html_text .= '<p><i>Note: This is an auto-generated email, please do not reply.</i></p>';
$html_text .= '</body></html>';


$autoReplyMessage = "Auto reply" . "\r\n\r\n".
"--" . $mime_boundary.
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit". "\r\n\r\n".
$plain_text.
"--" . $mime_boundary.
   "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".
   "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit". "\r\n\r\n".
$html_text.
"--".$mime_boundary."--";


mail($autoReplyTo, $autoReplySubject, $autoReplyMessage, $autoReplyheaders);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you don't want bother reading all the RFCs - why don't you use libraries (like phpmailer) that can send a well-formed and correct email?

Comment: check out here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9860369/1104695

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be the only issue, but you are missing line breaks after the `Content-Type` headers in the plain and HTML sections:

```
$autoReplyMessage = "Auto reply" . "\r\n\r\n".
"--" . $mime_boundary.
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n".
// ----------------------------------------------^^^^^
// Added \r\n
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit". "\r\n\r\n".
$plain_text. "\r\n".
//---------^^^^^^^^^
// Added another linebreak before MIME boundary
"--" . $mime_boundary.
   "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n".
// ----------------------------------------------^^^^^
// Added \r\n
   "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit". "\r\n\r\n".
$html_text."\r\n\r\n".
// ---------^^^^^^^^^^
"--".$mime_boundary."--";
```

Rather than attempt to craft multipart/mime messages manually, lots of us here on SO would recommend a mailing library like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) which handles this much more easily.  Building messages manually tends to be quite error-prone, and subject to inconsistencies between implementations by the SMTP server, or differences between native platform linebreaks.

Comment: hmm .. added line break .. still the same problem. will give PHPMailer a try may be. thanks

Comment: Also my host is running PHP 4.4.7. I wonder if that is going to be a problem.

Comment: @Shahid Looking over it again, I also see that you had only one linebreak after the `$plain_text` part, which was part of the string `$plain_text`. I added in another linebreak before the `--$mime_boundary` that follows `$plain_text`. That is probably the cause... Also, needed to add two linebreaks after `$html_text` before the final `--$mime_boundary--`

Comment: @Michael.. thanks .. however the problem is still there even after adding all those line breaks